# Detect property change

Tags: c#

Is there a way in which I can detect if a property value has changed but not when the object is initialized?

```
public string Foo
{
    set
    {
        // Register property has changed
        // but not on initialization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    private bool _initializing;

    private string _foo;
    public string Foo
    {
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
            if(!_initializing)
                NotifyOnPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    public Bar()
    {
        _initializing = true;
        Foo = "bar";
        _initializing = false;
    }
}
```

Or just skip the _initializing part and set _foo directly instead of using the setter.

Comment: This is a good method, but there is even a better way than the true/false flipping you do. Have your class implement [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx), this is very common in controls where there is special code that must be run *after* the user has input any special settings or enable methods that run on Propery changed but not when the property is being setup the first time (exactly like in the OP's case)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have implemented ISupportInitialize.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backing field, then you can set the field on initialization and the property thereafter.

```
private string foo;

public Bar()
{
    foo = "default"; // initialize without calling setter
}

public string Foo
{
    set
    {
        foo = value;
        // setter registers that property has changed
    }
}
```